# How to save multiple rows at one time in cakephp2.0?

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I am using cakephp 2.0 framework. I want to save multiple rows at one time here is my data

```
enter code here
 [EveAppointmentSlot] => Array
    (
        [appointment_from_time] => Array
            (
                [0] => 3:30 PM
                [1] => 3:30 PM
            )

        [appointment_to_time] => Array
            (
                [0] => 3:45 PM
                [1] => 3:45 PM
            )

    )

)
```

appointment_from_time zero index is 3:30pm and appointment_to_time index is zero :- 3:45pm and same as for other index
I want to save data in this table
[image]

Now when i want data when saved like

```
enter code here
appointment_from_ time       appointment_to_time
3:30 PM                          3:45 PM
3:30 PM                          3:45 PM
```

Here i have used this code but not working properly:-

```
enter code here
foreach($data['EveAppointmentSlot'] as $k=> $v){
                echo $k;
                foreach($data['EveAppointmentSlot'][$k] as $key=>$value){
                    $this->EveAppointmentSlot->create();
                    $this->EveAppointmentSlot->save($value);
                   }
        } echo "sucess"; die;
```

Comment: what do you mean by "*not working properly*" ? do you have error(s) ? wrong result ? no result ?

Comment: First off all how does that data come from ? If that come form any form post that form too.Then things would be mush easy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Your structure should be

   ```
   [EveAppointmentSlot] => Array
       (
           [0] => Array
               (
                   [appointment_from_time] => 3:30PM,
                   [appointment_to_time] => 3:45PM
               )
           [1] => Array
               (
                   [appointment_from_time] => 3:30PM,
                   [appointment_to_time] => 3:45PM
               )
       )
   ```
2. Also, the data should be converted to date data.

So from the data you already have, let's say in `$data`, this might help:

```
    $new_data = array();
    foreach( $data['EveAppointmentSlot'] as $attr => $slot ) {
        foreach( $slot as $i => $value ) {
            $new_data[$i][$attr] = date('H:i:s', strtotime($value));
        }
    }

    if( $this->EveAppointmentSlot->saveMany( $new_data ) ) {
        echo 'success';
    }
    else {
        echo 'failed';
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to format the data to save at first, then use `saveMany` to save them at once.

```
$dataToSave = array();
foreach($data['EveAppointmentSlot'] as $k => $d){
    $index = 0;
    foreach($d as $v){
        $dataToSave[$index][$k] = date("H:i:s", strtotime($v)); //Convert AM/PM time to 24h format supported by mysql.
        $index++;
    }
}
if($this->EveAppointmentSlot->saveMany($dataToSave)){
    echo "success";
}else{
    echo  "error";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your structure should be:

```
$new_data[EveAppointmentSlot] = Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [appointment_from_time] => 3:30PM,
            [appointment_to_time] => 3:45PM
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [appointment_from_time] => 3:30PM,
            [appointment_to_time] => 3:45PM
        )
)
```

Use this format and all records save in table.

```
if( $this->EveAppointmentSlot->saveAll( $new_data ) ) {
    echo 'success';
}
else {
    echo 'failed';
}
```